# viewing tortoisesvn diff of modified java svn files opens in ppt

Tags: windows-7, java, microsoft-powerpoint, tortoise-svn

I am getting this annoying behavior of opening my modified svn java files in ppt. When i do a svn diff it opens a ppt doc instead of using the existing tortoise svn diff tool. Any one has faced this before.

I am using windows 7, tortoise 1.8 version

Comment: check the tortoise svn settings under Diff Viewer

Comment: @megamorf tried all the settings.. Uninstalled svn and installed it back multiple times still no help...

Comment: Have you checked the advanced settings in the Diff Viewer section that specifies a viewer per file extension? Try to click restore defaults if you haven't changed anything there.

Comment: @megamorf Tried that too multiple times... If i give beyond compare tool as a diff viewer even then the diff opens a ppt doc..